# Prove that in Euclidean algorithm the remainders are decreasing at each successive step

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $r_1, r_2, ...$ be the successive remainders in the Euclidean algorithm applied to $a$ and $b$. 
It is obvious that the values of $a,b$ at each step are decreasing, in particular in two steps, the remainder transforms into $a$, and in one step into $b$, as shown below for the case of $r_3$:

$$a= bq_1+r_1$$
$$b=r_1q_2+r_2$$
$$r_1=r_2q_3+r_3$$ 
$$r_2=r_3q_4+r_4$$ 
$$r_3=r_4q_5+r_5$$

$$\vdots$$

This can be only used to show that after every two steps, the remainder is reduced by some ratio, I hope; but how to use to prove the title is not clear.

---

*1st edit:*
As per the comment by @saulspatz, it means that as the remainder will be determined by the divisor, and in any successive step the previous step's remainder is the divisor. The remainder at any $i$-th step will lie with in the bounds of $0$ to $r_i-1$. So, the remainder at the successive step will be on an average equal to half of the new divisor (or the old remainder).

Can I further use it to prove that: (A) in every two steps, the remainder is reduced by at least half, i.e. $r_{i+2} \lt \frac{1}{2}r_i$, for $i=1,2,...$

Comment: In each step after the first, the divisor is the remainder from the previous step.  The remainder in this step is less than the divisor by definition.

Comment: @saulspatz Please vet and help with the new question as shown in the edit to the OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1852297/206402 - [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852297/why-does-the-euclidean-algorithm-always-terminate/1852333#1852333) shows that 2 steps halve the size of the larger number.

Comment: @Joffan Please read my comment to your answer. I am confused over whether you achieve the reduction in one step or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $a=13, b=8$ then you get  $$
\begin{align}
r_1&=5\\
r_2&=3\\
r_3&=2\\
r_4&=1
\end{align}$$
Note that we started with two successive Fibonacci numbers, and that the remainders are successive Fibonacci numbers.

The Fibonacci numbers give the [worst behavior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477328/why-are-fibonacci-numbers-bad-for-euclids-algorithm-and-how-to-derive-this-uppe) for the Euclidean algorithm.  The successive Fibonacci numbers are in the ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ approximately, so $\frac{r_i=2}{r_i}\approx.382$

I do not know whether there is some example where $\frac{r_i=2}{r_i}\ge .5$ though I tend to doubt it.

Comment: I hope you mean that I can give the statement in the edited OP for the worst case of Euclidean algorithm given by the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: You accepted it too soon.  I misread your post.  This example actually satisfies $r_{i+2}<r_{i}.$  I had misread your post as $r_{i+1}<r_{i}.$

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What statement is that?

Comment: The question asks whether $r_{i+2}<r_i/2$, which actually happens in this example.

Comment: As your example states that the edited OP question regarding $r_{i+2} \lt \frac{1}{2} r_i$ is correct. But, you have shown also that this is true for the worst case example of Euclidean algorithm, as shown by the Fibonacci numbers being the successive remainders, as well as $a,b$. I meant that is the question valid for all, or only for cases when the worst case applies.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know.  See my earlier comment.  I'm trying to see if I can figure out the answer, before either editing or deleting this answer.

Comment: I feel that your answer was perfect, and request you to edit your current post (to remove typos), and assimilate with your old answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reconsidering your decision.

Comment: It's your question.  If the answer satisfies you, who am I to argue?

Answer (score 3):

If $r_{i+1}$ is not itself $\le \frac12r_i$, then $r_{i+2}$ will be exactly $r_i-r_{i+1}$, which will be less than $\frac12r_i$, so your conjecture is indeed correct.

But that does not represent the worst case, because in order for $r_{i+2}$ to be close to $\frac12r_i$, it will also have to be close to $r_{i+1}$, and then $r_{i+3}$ will be dramatically small.

The Fibonacci ratio represents the worst case that can be *sustained* over many steps of the algorithm -- deviating from it will sooner or later lead to a smaller $r_i$ than if you had started out with the exact golden ratio.

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple explanation for this.  I feel so stupid.